# += does not appear to be working with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

So I'm busy for school (this is not the actual assignment) and I need to get the input of this test function to be placed in this other variable, with the help of recursion.

I have experience with PHP for 4 years now and just learning Python, but I just don't get output of this function if I return name.

```
def test(string): 
   name = ''
   if len(string) == 0:
       return name
   else:
       name += string[0]
       test(string[1:])

test('name')
```

Comment: Each recursive call will initialise a new empty `name`. This function can only possibly return an empty string… PHP would behave the same BTW.

Comment: What's the expected return value?

Comment: You want to `return` from the `else` branch, too.

Comment: So I need to add another parameter and then it will work?

Comment: @Ironkey global variables are a bad idea.  Global variables used by a recursive function is even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each recursion name is initialized to empty string, pass it as a param instead.

```
def test(string, name = ''): 
   if len(string) == 0:
       return name
   return test(string[1:], name + string[0])

test('name')
```